# Is there any approximations for the partitions of an integer $n$, other than the Hardy-Ramanujan approx.?

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Is there any approximations for the partitions of an integer $n$, other than the Hardy-Ramanujan approx.? I'm just curious, there should be better approximations developed after them right?

Comment: There is even an exact formula by Rademacher. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540186/convergence-of-rademachers-formula-extending-the-partition-numbers-to-complex), for example.

Comment: Yes an exact formula is great but it is really huge and have complex functions inside functions. An approximate would be better right? The Hardy-Ramanujan one is simple enough. So is there any approximations?

Comment: All correct approximation should asymptotically be identical because they must necessarily converge to the same value. Hence we will never have a different approximation.

Comment: The approximation you've probably seen is the first term of an asymptotic expansion, and you can compute as many terms of that expansion as you want to get better and better approximations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas